# Duplicate Identifier in duplicate module

Tags: typescript

I have 2 files which contain the same module in my solution (different projects).

```
module myModule{
    export function doStuff(){} // in here "doStuff" is getting redlined
}
```

This error is obviously because i have 2 files with the same piece of code in it. But seeing as they don't reference each other or anything for that matter, i don't see how they can conflict.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, it treats all files as implicitly references all TypeScript files.

Therefore, if it thinks both modules have the same common root, it will think one is an extension of the other and will try to warn you about duplicate declarations.

Although you could argue that they aren't the same module, it is worth drawing some inspiration from framework class libraries, where they rarely rely on namespaces alone to distinguish between two classes, for example both of the following could have been called `Command`, but they have been distinguished by class name as well as namespace:

- `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`
- `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand`

Comment: sorry for being a slow ass. You'r answer is good but it doesn't solve my problem. The solution i went with was nesting the module. Which may or may not be better design. Personally i think TypeScript does a little too much gathering information from unrelated files when it throws errors from files that aren't linked in any way. Even if it does happen that they end up on the same page it doesn't break anything bcos the JS that TS generates handles that beautifully.